# Is there an (elegant) solution to constrain a generic type argument further within a method?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I have a generic base class `Foo<T>` from which the classes `Bar<U>` and `Bat<T>` derive.
`U` derives from `T`. Bat and Bar are similar implementations that differ only in a few places where values of type `U` must be handled in a different manner.

In `Foo`, I have a factory method `Create` that takes an argument of type `T` and should create either a `Bar` or `Bat` object. 
It looks roughly like this:

```
public static IFoo<T> Create(T input) {
  if (input.TypeIdentifier == Types.Bar) {// exemplary type check
    // input is of or derives from `U`
    // return a Bar<U>
  } else 
    return new Bat(input);
}

// usage:
U myU = new ClassThatDerivesFromU();
T myT = new ClassThatDerivesFromT(CouldBe.Of(Type.U));
var myFoo1 = Create(myU); // of type IFoo<U>
var myFoo2 = Create(myT); // of type IFoo<T>
```

Since `T` is not a `U`, I cannot instantiate a `Bar` object.

One possible solution would be this:

```
public static U To<T, U>(T input) where U : T {
  return input as U;
}

// to create Bar:
new Bar(To<T, U>(input));
```

However this is quite the hack imo and would not be usable with structs (`U` in this case cannot be a struct anyway due to inheritance, but I have another case where I want to call methods depending on if `T` is a `struct` or a `class` for example).

In C++ a scenario like this can be solved (iirc) by providing several overloads of the `Create` method with different type constraints and the compiler will check the type `T` and pick the right method (with either `U` or `T` as type constraint).

I'm not aware of a similar built-in solution in C#, but perhaps there is an elegant workaround I can use instead? (Reflection is an obvious answer, but not an option)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generic variance is allowed when using interfaces. You can declare the generic type parameter within IFoo to be either covariant or contravariant (depending upon the usage). If you wish to use a more derived type, then the type `T` must be contravariant and IFoo can be declared as follows:

```
interface IFoo<in T> { ... }
```

Have a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) for more information on generics and variance in C#.

**Update**

Once you have the condition that an `IFoo<U>` is `IFoo<T>` if `U : T` (eg the generic type of IFoo is contravariant) then you are free to safely cast within your create method:

```
return (IFoo<T>)((object)new Bar<U>());
```

Comment: That cast isn't necessary if `Bar<u>` implements `IFoo<T>`. My actual question, though, is how to create the Bar object since my parameter is only of type `T`, not `U`

Comment: @enzi The cast will be unless you constrain type `T` within the Create method to enable the compiler to verify that `Bar<U> : IFoo<T>` for all potential values of `T` (which you haven't according to your posted code)

Comment: you're right, I was looking at my code and not the example I provided above. I also updated the question a bit to provide more context.

Comment: @enzi Can you not just cast then: `return new Bar((T)input);`? If this is not the case, please post the full class and interfaces for the `Bar`, `Bat` and `Foo` types and the actual `Create` method.